# Is there a .NET attribute for specifying the "display name" of a property?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, attributes

Is there a property that allows you to specify a user friendly name for a property in a class?

For example, say I have the following class:

```
public class Position
{
     public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
     public ContactInfo EmployeeContactInfo { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to specify that the display name for the `EmployeeName` property is "Employee Name" and the display name for the `EmployeeContactInfo` property is "Employee Contact Information".

It's easy enough to write my own attribute class that allows me to do this:

```
[PropertyDisplayInfo(DisplayName = "Employee Name")]
public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
```

But is something like this already included in .NET?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is [`System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx)

Comment: as of .NET 4, there is a better attribute for this, System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute

Comment: For the benefit of other people looking for this answer, System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute is not supported by the Windows Forms DataGridView or PropertyGrid controls in .NET 4.0, so you're back to using System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute (and writing your own derived class if you want to support localization).

Answer (score 12):

`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute` is a better choice than `DisplayNameAttribute`, which is actually intended for use in property grids. Nowadays more components in the .NET world will pick up on and use `DisplayAttribute`. It also has niceties like `Order`, `GroupName`, `ShortName` and whether to display the property at all, when auto generation is done (with `AutoGenerateField`).

`DisplayAttribute` is also resource friendly, making it a good choice for localization.

Answer (score 3):

If you want this for debugging, you might be interested in the [DebuggerDisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Place the following attribute before each property declaration:

```
  //[DisplayName("Your desired human readable field caption ")]
    [DisplayName("ID")]
    public int id { 
        get {return _id;}
        set { SetField(ref _id, value, "id"); } 
    }
```