# Alternative name of a field for UI purposes

Tags: c#

I want to give a field (or property) an alternative name that can be shown in the user interface by using reflection. I have found the attribute `DescriptionAttribute`, but is it really for this purpose or am I better off using something else?

Is this attribute somehow restricted to Windows Forms and its property view, or is it UI framework independent? (currently I am on Windows Forms for the project, but it might change in the future so I don't want to be stuck with it)

```
public class MyCustomZoo
{
    [Description("Cute Mouse")] 
    public MyCustomAnimal CuteMouse;

    [Description("Frightning Lion")] 
    public MyCustomAnimal FrightningLion;
}
```

Comment: Did you read its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2)? Does what you read there fits your purpose?

Comment: Good Move! Now we already have three questions...

Comment: This is an X-Y problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem it looks like you're trying to add localisation to your UI, is this correct? If so, this is not the correct way to do so. Please update your question so that we understand what you're trying to do and why you're doing it.

Comment: @Kieran Devlin: I take localization only as a by-product. I appreciate your note about that not being the correct way. The main issue is about being able to show human readable names for the fields, that are not allowed by c# naming restrictions: e.g. "Fourier Analysis" for the display name instead of "FourierAnalysis" for the field in code.

Comment: Then you want to use `[DisplayName("Maus")]` as the description is used for describing the component. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Hmm, looks like DisplayName is not allowed on fields. Since I want the declaration of the inspected class as compact as possible, I'd rather only want to replace fields by auto properties if everything else fails...

Answer (score -1):

I have found my preferred solution in one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580347/is-there-a-net-attribute-for-specifying-the-display-name-of-a-property).

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

// ...

public class MyCustomZoo
{
    [Display(Name = "Cute Mouse")] 
    public object CuteMouse;

    [Display(Name = "Frightning Lion")] 
    public int FrightningLion;
}   

public static string FieldDisplayName(FieldInfo field)
{
    DisplayAttribute da = (DisplayAttribute)(field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false)[0]);
    return da.Name;
}

// ...

// c# identifier names, results in {"CuteMouse","FrightningLion"}   
List<string> fieldNames = typeof(MyCustomZoo).GetFields().Select(field => field.Name).ToList();

// "human readable" names, results in {"Cute Mouse","Frightning Lion"}  
List<string> fieldDisplayNames = typeof(MyCustomZoo).GetFields().Select(field => FieldDisplayName(field)).ToList();
```

Don't forget to add a reference to assembly `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.

**Note:** System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute could be used as well (thanks to Kieran Devlin) if properties is what you want to tag. With pure fields it doesn't work however.